# Selenium Webdriver / XPath: How to find element by attribute and the text of its children

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Given html:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">1 2 3</div>
    <div class="class3">a b c</div>
</div>
```

As i have several div elements in my html which uses the class "class1" and none has a id i want to find/fetch this parent element by the text of its children.

I tried different variants like

```
By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'class1') " 
    + "and text()[contains(.,'1 2 3')] "
    + "and text()[contains(.,'a b c')]]"));
```

but nothing seems to work yet.

In the example above i guess the text of the class1 element is checked but not of its children.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're looking for a `div` with class `class1` that has children with texts `1 2 3` and `a b c`. From your example of what you've tried, I'm assuming there are no further conditions (eg class) on the children:

```
//div[@class='class1' and div/text()='1 2 3' and div/text()='a b c']
```

You can make those children node names into `*` if you don't care whether they are `div`s or not. You can make the children node names prefixed by `descendant::` if you don't require them to be direct children.

Answer (score 1):

**Try any of these below mentioned xpath.**

**Using class attribute of `<div>` tag.**

```
//div[@class='class2']/..//div[@class='class3']/..//parent::div[@class='class1']
```

**Explanation of xpath:** First locate both child elements using the `class` attribute of `<div>` tag and then move ahead with `parent` keyword with `<div>` tag along with `class` attribute.

> OR

**Using text method along with `<div>` tag.**

```
//div[text()= '1 2 3']/..//div[text()= 'a b c']/..//parent::div[@class='class1']
```

**Explanation of xpath:** First locate both child elements using the `text` method of `<div>` tag and then move ahead with `parent` keyword with `<div>` tag along with `class` attribute.

These above `xpath` will locate your parent element `<div class="class1">`